# How push notification are delivered to iOS device without wifi and 3g?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, push-notification

While in most of the cases devs are complaining about missing notifications, I would like to ask how is it possible to get push notification on iOS device with wifi off and removed sim card. I have iPhone4 without sim card and the device is constantly in airplane mode (wifi off). I do sometimes turn wifi on but there were 3 cases when I have received push notification and double checked wifi was turned off with airplane mode on.

Maybe it's a coincidence, but I have noticed these notification started to appear a month ago. Is it a new iOS feature or it's some hidden mechanism that we could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I think you are talking about local notifications which can be set to fire like after a day or a few minutes for example.

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html

read more about UILocalNotification

I also found this blog which may help you http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/
you can go straight to number "4. scheduling notifications" to see the beefy part